# MVVM binding properties and subproperties

Tags: wpf, silverlight, mvvm, binding

I have a view model that inherits from a baseclass that has a property called IsReadOnly.
In this view model i have a property called Customer and i'm binding the properties of the customer object to controls on my view.

However i also want to be able to bind the IsReadOnly to each control on my view also.

```
<TextBox x:Name="FirstNameTextBox" Grid.Column="1" Margin="2,2,0,2" Grid.Row="2" TextWrapping="Wrap" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Width="200" 
                         Text="{Binding FirstName, Mode=TwoWay}" IsReadOnly="{Binding MyViewModel.IsReadOnly}"/>
```

How can i go about using both these properties?
here is my structure

public class MyViewModelBase {
    public bool IsReadonly { get;set;}
}

public class MyViewModel {
    public Customer Customer { get; set; }
}

public class Customer {
    public string FamilyName { get; set; }
}

Cheers for any help

Answer (score 0, accepted):

i assume that your MyViewModel inherit from MyViewModelBase.

```
public class MyViewModelBase { public bool IsReadonly { get;set;} }

public class MyViewModel : MyViewModelBase  { public Customer Customer { get; set; } }

public class Customer { public string FamilyName { get; set; } }
```

i also assume that your view DataContext is an instance of MyViewModel, if not let me know :) your binding should be like the following:

```
<TextBox x:Name="FirstNameTextBox" Grid.Column="1" Margin="2,2,0,2" Grid.Row="2"    TextWrapping="Wrap" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Width="200" 
         Text="{Binding Customer.FamilyName, Mode=TwoWay}" IsReadOnly="{Binding IsReadOnly}"/>
```

EDIT: if the DataContext of your TextBox is the Customer Property, you have to use RelativeSource in your Binding to IsReadOnly

Comment: thanks, that fixed my problem. Good to know that you can do Property Traversing. :)

Answer (score 7):

Property traversing works with Binding too, so you can do the following to bind to IsReadonly property of the base object:

```
public class MyViewModel {
    public Customer Customer { get; set; }
}

public class Customer : Entity {
}

public class Entity {
    public bool IsReadonly { get;set;}
}

<Button IsEnabled="{Binding Customer.IsReadonly}" />
```

For the above example, I'm supposing your view is bound to an instance of "MyViewModel" and you probably already have property notification change on your properties.

Comment: hi Hadi, i see what your saying. So i bind my Customer to a Grid's DataContext and inside the Grid i have TextBoxes that are bound to the Customer properties. But i also want to bind the IsEditable, IsReadOnly to the viewModel IsReadOnly property. Is it possible?